# Elegantly adding m4 macro processor into gcc compilation chain?

Tags: c, gcc, c-preprocessor, m4

I thought about playing around with `m4`'s extra macro processing features (over the regular `cpp` preprocessor) by merely, simply including it in the invoked chain of tools during the GCC compilation (rather right before `cpp`, so looks like as the first invoked command), however I don't know how to do it, i.e.: how to make `m4` invoked as the (apparently) first stage of C gcc compilation of each of the input `.c` files. Is there some elegant method of achieving this?

**Update**: Apparently, the question might be more about build tools like autotools and CMake. I would be more interested in autotools.

Comment: Don't do this in GCC, do it in your Makefile.

Comment: @Barmar: You might be right. I've updated the question.

Comment: `I would be more interested in autotools` Just add it to makefile.am, literally `file.c: file.c.m4       m4 $< > $@` , make will pick it up. As for cmake, just `add_custom_command` it, I did [some more work](https://gitlab.com/Kamcuk/kcmakelib/-/blob/master/cmake/k/m4.cmake) with GNU m4 and CMake to track `m4_include(dependencies)` from m4 and automatically recompile if dependencies changes, but I doubt the library is "user ready".